# Upload - Exclude File Type

Tags: regex, phpstorm

I'm currently using Node.js and minifying CSS and JS files with PHP Storm 7.1 and I'd like to only upload the *.min version of the file.

I'm not certain how to even go about this. Can a regular expression be used here? If yes, which expression would work best?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching online and trying multiple options I came up with the following regex which seems to do the job:

```
*[^min].css;*[^min].js
```

I set this under File -> Settings -> Deployment -> Options for Exclude items by name.

Running a manual upload it appears only the .min.css / .min.js files are being uploaded which is exactly what I was looking for.